# lisp (scheme) function that works with and without an argument

Tags: scheme, lisp

I'm working on an assignment where I have to construct a function which takes a single argument and returns various things. However, it is also supposed to do something when it is evaluated without an argument and I don't know how to do this. Does anyone know how one would go about implementing such a function? Could I perhaps set a condition that if it is evaluated with an argument it does x and if there is no argument it does y?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the form

```
(define g (lambda args ...body...))
```

for that. `args` will be bound to the *list* of all the supplied arguments in the function call. You can analyze it and take appropriate decisions inside your function's `...body...`.

A famous and very nice example is

```
(lambda args args)
```

What's the name of this function?

Another syntax for defining such functions is

```
(define (g . args) args)
```

And to define a function that must get, say, at least two arguments, you'd write

```
(define (foo a b . c) ...body...)

; (define foo (lambda (a b . c) ...body...))
```

where `a` will be the first argument, `b` the second, and `c` will be the list of all the rest of arguments in the function call (possibly empty).

Answer (score 1):

Scheme, as in R5RS compliant, R6RS, and R7RS:

```scm
(define (proc . arg-rest)
  (define arg
    (if (null? arg-rest)
        'default-arg1
        (car arg-rest)))

  ;; use arg 
  arg)

(proc)   ; ==> 'default-arg1
(proc 1) ; ==> 1
```

If the parameters are not a proper list then the dotted symbol represent the rest of the arguments as a list. The example above takes no mandatory arguments. For completeness here are one with one mandatory:

```scm
(define (proc man1 . arg-rest)
  ...)
```

[SRFI-89 Optional positional and named parameters](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-89/srfi-89.html) is an extension to R5RS. Many implementations come with many SRFIs already implemented and those who don't can take the reference implementation. Some implementations even works like this with `define`, but it is not portable.

```scm
(define* (proc (arg 'default-arg1))
  ;; use arg 
  arg)

(define* (proc man1 (arg 'default-arg1))
  ...)
```

[SRFI-16 Case lambda](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-16/srfi-16.html) is an alternative and is shipped with R6RS:

```scm
(define proc  
  (case-lambda 
    (() (proc 'default-arg1))
    ((arg) 
     ;; use arg
     arg)))

(define proc  
  (case-lambda 
    ((man1) (proc man1 'default-arg1))
    ((man1 arg) 
     ...)))
```

And since you have tagged LISP I'll add Common Lisp version of positional optional arguments:

```lisp
(defun fun (&optional (arg 'default-arg1))
  arg)

(defun fun (man1 &optional (arg 'default-arg1))
  ...)
```